# Upload images with ajax and nodejs using Formdata - CORS error issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am using vanilla javascript (AJAX) to post a form and using Formdata(). The submission of form is captured by nodejs and connecting to database.

The issue is while i am sending normal data to nodejs, I am able to connect database and response as success. But while I am adding a file upload input(to store file path) and trying to connect, the CORS error is coming. I have set header for allow cross origin as * value in express(nodejs).

HTML:

```
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="textareaLbl2">Description 2</label>
            <textarea  name="descr2" class="form-control" id="textareaLbl2" rows="3"></textarea>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="img">Upload:</label>
            <input type="file" name="img" class="form-control" id="img" />
          </div>
```

JS:

```
testForms.onsubmit = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var formData = new FormData(testForms);
    request.open( "POST", "https://xyz.domain.com/addList", true);
    request.send(formData);
}
```

Nodejs:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    // Website you wish to allow to connect
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

    // Request methods you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

    // Request headers you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work? If not have you tried the cors middleware:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

```
 app.use(function (req, res, next) {

    // Website you wish to allow to connect
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

    // Request methods you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

    // Request headers you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');

    // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
    // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

    // Pass to next layer of middleware
    next();
});
```

Also try setting Content-Type on node side.

Comment: Is there any more detail in the cors error, have you tried with postman etc. Maybe try and add these before the .send()  xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
     xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');